# Unable to align text to right of imageview android layout xml

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create layout like below in android:
[image: Layout]

But my problem is I am unable to  add textbelow  the image or on the right hand side of imageview. If I wrap ImageView and textview in a LinearLayout the then the whole view shrinks. Should I be using TableLayout?

My current layout xml is like below:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_margin="30dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"


        >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/vwImageAndClassroom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_room"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/coverimage_contentdescription"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/comm_book_icon"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_emp_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/img_room"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TEXT 1"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"


        >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/vwImageAndClassroom2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_room2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/coverimage_contentdescription"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/visitor_book_icon"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_emp_name2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/img_room2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TEXT 2"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"


        >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/vwImageAndClassroom3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_room3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/coverimage_contentdescription"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/visitor_book_icon"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_emp_name3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/img_room3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TEXT 3"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please show the output screen of this xml design of yours above mentioned picture does not correspond the information very well with provided xml

Comment: @snowflakes which one? Or all at once?

Comment: @Rizwanatta Thank you please see my updated xml ..it is almost what I am trying to achieve. The only thing that is not working is ability to add text to the right of the third imageview as per the illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you and you will find your solutions from this xml code. I just modify some of your code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This Right side text 1"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This Right side text 1"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This Right side text 1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is under layout text"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is under layout text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you please have a look at my updated layout in my question. It is almost what I am trying to achieve except I just want two more textfields align to the right of the imageview (img_room3)

Comment: Please check the latest update. Hope this will be okay

Answer (score 1):

Have placeholder views where text is not required.

[image]

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/next_green" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/next_green" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/next_green" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly what you want

[Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ0to.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="Some text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="Some text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some text"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Some text"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```